# Finding a function which is defined by a function of it's integral

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, integral-equations

How can I find $f(x)$  in below relation?

$f(x)= e^{I}$

$I = c_1 e^{-x^2/x0^2} - \int_0^\inf (\frac{c_2 (x_2 - x)}{(c_3^2+(x2-x)^2)^{\frac{5}{2}}}+ \frac{c_4(x2-x1)}{(c_3^2+(x2-x1)^2)^{\frac{7}{2}}})\: \: f(x_2) \: \: x_2 \:\:d x_2 $

in which, $c_i$ are real constants(for simplicity one can put them equal to 1).

Comment: If you substitute `I=Log[f[x]]`(1. equation) into the second, you get a complicated integral-equation. Unfortunately DSolve can't solve it...

Comment: You may wish to ask the people over at https://math.stackexchange.com/ as well, as this doesn't appear to specifically be a _Mathematica_ issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think, there is no chance to do this analytically. But you can get fine numerical solution if you iterate finding f[x] for each x.

NestList shows, you reach a fixed point for f[x] after enough iterations.

```
f[x_, x0_, x1_, fstart_, n_] := NestList[Exp[
       Exp[-x^2/x0^2] - 
       NIntegrate[((x2 - x)/(1 + (x2 - x)^2)^(
       5/2) + (x2 - x1)/(1 + (x2 - x1)^2)^(7/2)) # x2, {x2, 
       0, \[Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 50]] &, fstart, n]

ListLinePlot[f[1, 2, 3, 1, 100]]
```

[image]

Therefore work fith FixedPoint

```
fp[x_, x0_, x1_, fstart_] := FixedPoint[
     Exp[Exp[-x^2/x0^2] - 
     NIntegrate[((x2 - x)/(1 + (x2 - x)^2)^(
      5/2) + (x2 - x1)/(1 + (x2 - x1)^2)^(7/2)) # x2, {x2, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, MaxRecursion -> 50]] &, fstart, 
     SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < 1*^-8 &)]
```

And plot a solution

```
pl = Plot[fp[x, 2, 3, 1], {x, -6, 6}, Mesh -> All]
```

[image]

If you generate an interpolation function

```
fip = Interpolation[Cases[pl, {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, {6}], 
      InterpolationOrder -> 5]
```

you can even differentiate the found f[x]

```
Plot[fip'[x], {x, -6, 6}]
```

[image]